# Issues integrating Facebook Share in my SPA application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook

This question is specifically for client-side JavaScript developers with experience integrating Facebook Share buttons.

My SPA application is developed using JavaScript and AngularJS.

As part of the functionality, there is a page with a couple of divs, each presenting a list of documents references, each reference with its own status.

The divs include a `ng-show` directive, such that only one of the two divs is presented at any given time.

This information (lists of documents) is received from the remote server and arranged within a JSON collection (array), where each entry includes the document title, its status, and an encoded string (later on its use will become clear).

The documents may be in two statuses: EDIT or VIEW.

What I want to do is to add next to each document a SHARE button with a URL that would look as follows:

```
  http://MyTestSite.com/Index.html?action=<action>&reference=<reference>
```

where `<action>` may be either EDIT or VIEW and the `<reference>` will be the encoded string. For instance:

```
  http://MyTestSite.com/Index.html?action=view&reference=23lkj32oi4j23kl2j2lk2l34kj23
```

A visitor that clicks on this URL (with the parameters) will be directly routed to the view page of the relevant document (as specified by the encoded string).

I am using the following code as extracted from Facebook's site:

Once within the page:

```
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
    );
</script>
<style>
    .fb-share-button
    {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
        -o-transform: scale(1.5);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
        transform-origin: top left;
        -ms-transform-origin: top left;
        -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
        -moz-transform-origin: top left;
        -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    }
</style>
```

For each document reference:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
        aria-haspopup="true" 
        aria-expanded="false" 
        style="width:100%;height:40px;text-align:left">
    <div id="fb-root" style="width:100%;height:0px;margin:-10px 0 0 0 "></div>

    <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="{{Get_Path_for_Facebook(One_Article)}}" data-layout="button"></div>
</button>
```

Notes:

- I'm wrapping Facebook's button with one of my own since I'm offering other options that are not related to Facebook and I want all the options to look the same.
- The function `Get_Path_for_Facebook(One_Article)` returns a string that includes the whole path (e.g. `http://MyTestSite.com/Index.html?action=view&reference=23lkj32oi4j23kl2j2lk2l34kj23`).

So, here are my problems:

1. When I am viewing one of the two divs and click on any of the SHARE buttons I get the Facebook login window. This works repeatedly if I click at different documents within the same div. As soon as I switch to the other div, the Facebook logo is no longer shown and, obviously, nothing happens when clicking on the button.

   I should add that it does not matter which div I begin with, Facebook's login window will appear the first time and any additional time I click on the SHARE button as long as I remain within the same div, and will stop working as soon as I switch div.
2. How can I share a URL that includes parameters as exemplified above?

This is not the first post I have created for this issue. I got a suggestion of building a server-side page (or something like that) which is far beyond my current knowledge.

### Edit

From the feedback received, it would appear that my question is not clear, so here is a different approach to describe it.

I want to reach a situation in which links shared from my SPA application appear within Facebook and, when clicking on them, a separate window/tab is open with the URL of the link. This is much the same as when you get a link in an e-mail and click on it.

Now, these links would look like:

```
  http://MyTestSite.com/Index.html?action=view&reference=dfklj34lkdjawoet4jw4oige9034
```

and are dynamically generated within my SPA.

Though obvious, it is important to note that my SPA uses these parameters such that, for instance, the visitor would be brought directly to the view of the document without the need to log into the application and search for the document.

My SPA has two **divs** whose visibility is conditioned by an `ng-show` directive. Each such **div** contains a list of documents (being the list a result of `ng-repeat`).

I want to display, next to each listed document, a SHARE button that will share a link like the example above (but with different parameters of course).

It is important to note that I don't need anything of my page to be shown neither within the Share window nor within Facebook's page. Only a link and, (if the sharing user wishes) a
comment.

My problems are:

1) How do I share a link with parameters like shown above?

2) I am using the sample code shown above and, while starting and remaining within one of the **divs** all the share buttons cause a Facebook window to pop (and this regardless of which **div** I started). As soon as I switch from one **div** to the other, share buttons stop showing at all.

### Edit 2

I should add that the best solution for me would be if I could use buttons of my own (instead of Facebook's) and have the sharing mechanism handled within a function of the page's controller.

Comment: Hello @CBroe. Yes, I am asking a question about the same problem, but with different phrasing and more explanations of what I need, and this with the hope that I do get a **solution** (as opposed to an **answer** that does not solve my problem) I will be able to understand and realize. If you take a look at the same from John Smith you will see that there is an answer but it is not a solution to my problem. Thanks for reverting your mark as duplicate.

Comment: By switching between the divs with the `ng-show` directive, you are dynamically adding HTML elements to the DOM - and the duplicate (to your first version of this question) explains why this is problematic in regard to the FB social plugins, and what you have to do about it.

Comment: As for your second question, "How can I share a URL that includes parameters as exemplified above?" - like any other UR that _doesn't_ have extra parameters. Facebook only cares about the URL, and what content your server delivers when that URL is requested. And therefor you will need some sort of server-side rendering, if you want to share content on Facebook and use Open graph meta tags while doing so.

Comment: And FYI, there is still a way to specify those parameters at runtime (instead of via server-side rendered OG meta tags), if you use the Feed dialog instead of the share button. (But I would not rely on that to much, and expect that this will be removed at some point in the future as well, because it just gets abused too much.)

Comment: Thank you very much @CBroe for your words. I think I'm starting to get things cleared and, perhaps, my question is misleading. I don't want anything to be displayed within Facebook's framework. The only thing I want is that, when a Facebook user clicks on a **shared link** a new browser tab opens OUTSIDE FACEBOOK at the given URL with the parameters. That tab will be at my application, that knows what to do with the parameters.

Comment: By the way, I learned that `ng-show`, as opposed to `ng-if` does not create/destroy elements within the DOM. Had this issue before and got a recommendation to use `ng-show`, solving my problem.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes it even less clear to me what your actual problem is.

Comment: I know it is against the protocol of this site (and perhaps yours as well), but is there a way I can send you a clear description of what I need to achieve without creating yet another question in here?

Comment: You can edit this question.

Comment: OK. Will do (within the next 6 hours). Hope you catch the edit and it will be clear enough. Thanks!!

Comment: Hello @CBroe. I added two comments hoping things are more clear now.

Comment: Not really. What is your actual problem with sharing those links with parameters? It works the same way, as if it didn’t have parameters. / _“and have the sharing mechanism handled within a function of the page's controller”_ – that would require that you make the post via API, and that in turn requires that users log in to your app and grant it permission to post in their name first.

Comment: Maybe you want to try the Share dialog or the Feed dialog instead? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web With those, you can use your own button/link/any HTML element, and then trigger the dialog that allows the user to share either via FB.ui – or simply use the URL redirection version, with a simple link with target=_blank

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. Will investigate these and give it a try. I assume you know these mechanisms and know they provide the required functionality, right?

Comment: OK. I found a working solution using the sharer. Though depreciated, it is simple and does exactly what I need (tested already). Thank you @CBroe for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution using Facebook's sharer in this example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
    var value = $("input").val();
    var sharerURL = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="

    var shareURL = sharerURL + value;

    window.open(shareURL, "_blank");
  });
});
```

There is a working demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOdVXr?editors=1111

I created a simple function within my controller which does the job, exactly the way I needed. I know it is depreciated, but it works perfectly the way I want and, most of all, it is straightforward.